# Построить графовое дерево python

Tags: python, frontend, flask, графы, dash

Хочу рисовать в браузере граф, как [здесь](https://graphonline.ru/), чтобы потом отправить его на вычисления? Есть ли возможность сделать это средствами python? И можно ли воспользоваться фреймворком Dash?
Готов рассмотреть варианты и без использования браузера.

Answer (score 0):

Для удобной работы с графами есть библиотека NetworkX.
Можешь почитать про неё на хабре.

В graphonline используется насколько я знаю движок arbor.js.
Поэтому если хочешь как на graphonline, то поднимай сервак с помощью flask или django и подрубай туда js. В котором будет исполняться скрипт созданный шаблонизатором одним из модулей.